# The answer of the count is 88: why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">{{count()}}</div>
    <script>

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.listarray=[1,2,3,4];
        var count=0    

        $scope.count = function() {
            angular.forEach($scope.listarray,function(value,key){
                count=count+1;
            });
            return count;
        }
     });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The answer shown by the above code is `88`. When the `var count` is inside `count` function is shows `4` but outside the `count` function it shows `88`. Why does it happen?

Comment: o really it's showing 88? Can you show me the result in fiddler?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/0s12zf1k/ , Just define `var count` inside function. _OR_ YOu can simply use `listarray.length` like http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Lc4yvbc9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the behavior is that you've attached the `count()` function to `$scope` and used it inside of a binding expression.  In AngularJS, the `$digest` cycle to evaluate expressions and render the view can run multiple times.

In pseudo code the `$digest` cycle looks something like this:

1. For each `$scope` property
2. Check if `$scope` property changed (by evaluating binding expressions for example)
3. If changed, call change handler (which may update more scope variables), otherwise continue
4. Repeat for all scopes
5. Repeat cycle 1-4 until `$scope` properties stabalise

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using function or each loop you could just use the **length** property    ***$scope.listarray.length;***
Try this:

```
<head>
<script src=        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">        </script>
    </head>

  <body>

 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">
 {{count}}

  </div>

 <script>

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.listarray=[1,2,3,4];

   $scope.count =  $scope.listarray.length;    
     });
   </script>

    </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've created infinite loop. Becouse your function count() called every time when the value changes. For example you could check if the value had already been changed

```
 $scope.count = function() {
        if(count !== 0){return count;}
        angular.forEach($scope.listarray,function(value,key){
            console.log('value', value);
            count=count+1;
        });
        return count;
    }
```